# How do I use SQL intersect operator in Pandas dataframe on databricks

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm using python 3.x on databricks. I have two dataframe,a & b. a contains 2 rows & b contains 5 rows. While I'm merging this two dataframe using below command

```
combine=pd.merge(a,b,on=[...],how="inner")
```

I'm getting 10 rows. But I need 5 rows or maximum number of rows in the dataframe. I tried to implement SQL intersect using following code

```
combine=a.merge(b)
```

Again I got 10 rows. Can you suggest me how do I implement intersect in Python.

Comment: This is probably because you merge (join) two tables on nonunique keys (column values) which gives an output of 5x2=10 records. First you need to define which key you will use to join two tables. Also clearly explain your table content and desired output, so people can see details of your tables and your problem.

Comment: @highlytrainedbadger, I have following Keys, class, section, id, phone & yes those are unique.If I'm taking unique of the keys then I'm getting one record. For the same key A has 2 record & b has 5 record.. After merging I'm getting 10 records but again if I take unique of the keys only then I'm getting 1 record

Comment: You probably confuse `DISTINCT` and uniqueness. I suggest you to review the following documentation to have an idea for join/merge my friend: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging. Look how keys of two tables match and gives a result as you desire: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/_images/merging_merge_on_key.png

Comment: @highlytrainedbadger,no. I'm doing merge using where='inner'. An inner merge, (or inner join) keeps only the common values in both the left and right dataframes for the result. So my expectation was I should get maximum row count after merge is equal to the maximum row count of the two dataframe for the given conditions. But I'm getting rowcount as multiplication of rowcounts of both the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
result = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1, join='inner')
```

will give the following result:

[image]

I suggest you read this walkthrough to get exact what you want:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. I tried result = pd.concat([a, b],,keys=[], axis=1, ignore_index=True,join='inner') but I'm getting RangeIndex(start=0, stop=27, step=1) instead of column names. Also I tried reindex(a) but resetindex is giving multilevel columns. I need the individual column names. Can you please suggest